# Solving Weird Exponential Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am working on my math homework when I encountered a difficult problem. I simplified the equation and substituted smaller numbers to get this:

> $n*2^n>10$

I have tried standard algebraic methods with logarithms, but I could not get them to work. Researching online, I came across the Lambert W function, but I know I don't need it to get the answer, as the math class I am taking is not that advanced. I strongly prefer not to use it.

If anyone can figure out the answer and explain, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If $n$ must be an integer, this equation holds for all $n\ge 3$.

Comment: I think the only way to solve that equation is to use the Lambert W function or you could just try integers (if $n$ is an integer) to see what works. As @vadim123 states $n\geq 3$ since the actual solution is approximately: $n>2.1906$.

Comment: @vadim123, how did you figure that out?

Comment: @Jay, I would like to just try integers, but my teacher would probably prefer a better method than guess and check.

Comment: @alexwho314 I don't think there is any other method that's much better than guessing and checking. You could use various numerical methods but that's hardly better. I'm fairly sure there isn't another way of solving an equation of the form $x a^x=b$ with elementary functions. Unless you've made an error in getting that equation then I can't see an obvious way of doing this without guessing and checking (and without using the Lambert W function).

Comment: A method that could work but is slowly is to write

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{\ln(10) - \ln(x_n)}{\ln(2)}$$

and start with $x_1=3$, then you repeat this and you get

$$
x_{20} = 2.190775613...\\
x_{36} = 2.190600886...
$$

Comment: What class is this? Do you have logarithms available? Pretty obvious brute force is by all accounts the best method, by inspection. But fore bigger numbers in place of ten there are good heuristics.

Comment: Note that $n2^n$ is increasing, so check for $1$, $2$, and bingo! So all the solutions are $x\ge 3$.

Comment: Well, don't feel so bad about it being impossible to solve using elementary function. To look at this another way... Clearly $n$ cannot be rational (prove using the rational root theorem and prime factorization to show that if $2^{\frac{p}{q}}$ is rational then $q|p$). Thus $n$ is irrational. If $n$ were to be algebraic, then by Gelfond–Schneider theorem $2^{n}$ must be transcendental, but $\frac{10}{n}$ is algebraic, contradiction. I don't know how to prove that $n$ cannot be obtained if $\exp$ and $\log$ is allowed, if anyone know please tell. But that shows partly why $n$ is hard to get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you remember how to graph exponential and reciprocal functions by hand? If so, rearrange to:

$$2^n > \frac{10}{n}$$

The inequality is reversed if $n<0$, but it is obvious that no such solutions exist, so we ignore that case.

Then sketch the graphs by hand, note the intersection is around $n=2$, and test values $n=2$ and $n=3$ manually.

[image: Graphs]

If you don't remember how to graph exponential and reciprocal functions, you can use numerical methods to approximate the point of intersection. Near zero, $2^n \approx \ln{2} \cdot (1+n+\frac{n^2}{2})$ (the first three terms of the Maclaurin sequence).

Using the well known approximation $\ln{2} \approx 0.7$, we can find the intersection by solving the polynomial:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
10 &\approx 0.7 \left(n+n^2+\frac{n^3}{2}\right) \newline
0 &\approx 7n^3 + 14n^2 + 14n - 200
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Use a standard scientific calculator to solve the above, to obtain $n \approx 2.3$.

We then, once again, check $n=2$ and $n=3$ manually.

Comment: Thank you very much. As much as I would like to avoid a graphical method of solving, that must be what I have to do.